# PHP Child Class Property Inheritance

Tags: php

I have a base class called `Parent`.  Within parent I am setting a class property, `$this->admin = TRUE`;

I also have a child class we'll call `Child`.  The constructor for `Child` calls the parent constructor.  I was under the impression that when you set a class property int he parent class, that property is inherited by the child, unless you override it.  yet when I test to see if `$this->admin` is set I get false.  Did I get the concept of inheritance wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting this property?  Can you show us some code?  The `Child` class will have an `admin` property, but when you set this property, you are setting it for a specific instance of the class.

Comment: If Admin is a private property then it wont be inherited, make sure its protected.

Comment: A side note: `$this->admin` is an _object_ property. Each object has it's own set of properties and their values are not shared. _Class_ property would be `self::$admin`, and the value is shared among all objects of one class.

Answer (score 0):

A **class property** cannot be access with $this->prop, but only with self::$prop, also, make sure that the property is not set to `private` but to `public` or `protected` so that it will be inherited to child classes.